# Iterate over bus signals in Simulink / Reuse subsystems without copying

Tags: matlab, simulink

In Simulink, I need to perform the same (non-trivial) operation on multiple buses.
I thought about implementing that operation as a subsystem and reuse it, but that didn't work out well.

I wonder now if it is possible to iterate the signals/buses within a bus to apply the same operation multiple times and then bundle the results together again. How would I do that?

Comment: Could you be a little more precise on the problems you had with subsystems? Is that relative to the different names of signals among the busses?

Comment: I need the subystems to be separate models. When they are in accelerator mode they won't compile, but when I switch them to normal mode I can only use one instance.

Answer (score 1):

What release are you using?  If you are using R2010b or later, you can use an array of buses and a for-each subsystem.  See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/bsocrb0.html) for more details on how this works. This will only work if the the multiple buses that you want to iterate have exactly the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab to test this solution now. I assume your busses are all of the same dimension and structure.

- Create a block in a library
- Define a type (bus object) with the bus editor (corresponding to the
  common structure of your busses)
- Set the `inport` and the `outport` to this type.
- Use the `bus selector` to decompose your data, perform your
  operations and reassemble your busses with a `bus creator`. The names
  in the selector/creator are those of the type you defined.
- Use this block on each signal.
- Don't forget to export the type to a .mat file and to load it.

Comment: Library blocks are what I am doing now. Is there some sort of generic solution that does not depend on the number of elements in the bus - something like a foreach loop?